# xsl:apply-templates: match not being respected

Tags: xslt

I'm having a problem with xsl:apply-templates. I am attempting to apply a template to one particular tag, but I am seeing text from other tags. A simple xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                  

<!-- execute with xsltproc foo.xsl foo.xml -->                         
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"                                          
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >     

    <xsl:output method="text" />                                       

    <xsl:template match="/foo">                                        
        <xsl:for-each select="bar">                                    
            <xsl:value-of select="grill"/>                             
            <xsl:apply-templates match="baz"/>                         
        </xsl:for-each>                                                
    </xsl:template>                                                    

    <xsl:template match="foo">[<xsl:value-of select="." />|http://example.com/<xsl:value-of select="." />]</xsl:template>                     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The input is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<foo>
    <bar>
        <baz>a <foo>b</foo> c</baz>
        <grill>grill</grill>
    </bar>
</foo>
```

The output is:

```
grill
        a [b|http://example.com/b] c
        grill
```

I was expecting the output to be

```
grill
a [b|http://example.com/b] c
```

(I don't care about the spacing problems for now)

I can get around the problem with wrapping the xsl:apply-templates with a xsl:for-each:

```
<xsl:for-each select="grill">
    <xsl:apply-templates match="grill"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But I really don't like this solution. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute `match` isn't allowed on the `xsl:apply-templates` element. Change `match` to `select` in the `xsl:apply-templates` and try it again.